# PC (Win 10) goes into power saving mode when video or youtube playback is stopped

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, youtube

Title says it.

When i watch youtube videos, after some videos the video playback is paused by a popup which asks the user if youtube shall continue playing.
If i do not react within a few minutes, my pc goes into power saving mode.. which should only happen after 30 minutes of inactivity.

Same happens when watching other online videos (netflix, amazon prime) and the video is over.

I use chrome for watching videos.

Is this a problem with windows 10 or chrome which switches my pc into power saving mode?

And more important, how can this be disabled?

Comment: Check power advanced settings from control panel

Comment: Programs tell Windows not to sleep (two option system or system and display). But the timer is still ticking. You need to use the computer. _Activities that are automatically detected include local keyboard or mouse input, server activity, and changing window focus. Activities that are not automatically detected include disk or CPU activity and video display._ https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate